# Converting from GraphData to graph object

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I know this is a simple question, but suppose I have a graph

```
G = Part[GraphData[n],i]
```

How do I convert this into a graph object accepted by `PlanarGraphQ`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica!   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

Part[GraphData[n],i] is just the name of graph.  Apply GraphData to the name:

```
GraphData[Part[GraphData[3], 3]]
```